# Text wrongly aligned in container/box (CSS properties)

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with my PHP/CSS.
So here's what I'm trying to do (photoshoped) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ElxD.png

And here's what I get :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/suLeO.png

My PHP body looks like this :

```
<body>
  <h2>Classique</h2>
  <div class="container-lobby">
    <div class="box-lobby">Liste des joueurs
      <ul class="joueurs-ul">
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 1</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 2</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box-lobby">Paramètres
      
      <ul class="joueurs-ul">
        <li class="joueurs-li">Timer :</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Pénalités :</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Nombre de manches :</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Filtre catégories :</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here are the properties that should affect it :

```
.container-lobby {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.box-lobby {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  width: 440px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.joueurs-li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.joueurs-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I've tried many things with text-align/justify-content, etc...
I don't understand why :

1. My "Listes des joueurs" doesn't center and has like 25px margin in the box (left) and "Paramètres" doesn't have the same settings, it sticks to the left of the box.
2. Why my actual li/ul content sticks to the right of the boxes (but is aligned left like I want it to be).

Sorry for my poor english in those explanations.

Anyone got an idea ?

Thank you !

I've tried in container/box/ul/il to edit :
text-align: left
justify-content
I forgot the arguments that I tried and didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `.box-lobby` container is a flexbox (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). This is causing all child elements to be dynamically sized into the box. To better understand how flexbox affects elements, encase your titles (Ex: Liste des joueurs) into paragraph (`<p>`) tags, and display the border of all elements with

```
* {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This will show you how, technically, your title is side-by-side with your `ul` and not on top of it.

Removing `display-flex` from `.box-lobby` in CSS fixes your issue. But, assuming you want to use flexbox:

You will need to modify `.box-lobby` to use

```
// .box-lobby    
flex-wrap: wrap; // Allows flex items to appear on multiple lines instead of squeezed onto one.
```

And modify your `.jouers.ul` to use

```
// .jouers.ul    
width: 100%; // Allows this ul to occupy an entire line, thus giving it a block status.
```

These changes result in this code:

```css
.container-lobby {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.box-lobby {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  width: 440px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
}

.joueurs-li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.joueurs-ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-lobby">
    <div class="box-lobby">
     Liste des joueurs
      <ul class="joueurs-ul">
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 1</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 2</li>
        <li class="joueurs-li">Joueur 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot for the work and the explanations.
The CSS did it for me, when I try the PHP you edited, as you jumped a line, the Paramètres block skips a line too. But not changing it works perfectly now for me !